# jQuery submit loads form data in url but doesn't post to ColdFusion cfc

Tags: jquery, json, url, post, coldfusion

I am trying to pass form data into a ColdFusion component. I load the form with an ajax get request then fill out the form then hit the submit button to pass the form data into the cfc. The problem is the ajax post throws an error the first time but the form data is loaded into the URL. When I hit submit again it works fine. If I change the form data after the first submit then I get the same error. What is going on here?

Here is the submit function:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#update',function() {
    $linkName = $('#update').find('#linkName').val();
    $linkURL = $('#update').find('#linkURL').val();
    $linkInfo = $('#update').find('#linkDesc').val();
    $numOfLinks = $('.linkSection').length;
    if ($numOfLinks > 0){
    // Here the sub link names and urls put into an array
        $subLinkName = [];
        $subLinkURL = [];   
        $('.linkSection').each(function(index, element) {
        $subLinkName.push($(this).find('#subLinkName').attr('value'));
            $subLinkURL.push($(this).find('#subLinkURL').attr('value'));
            $data = {linkName: $linkName, linkURL: $linkURL, linkID : $linkID, linkDescription : $linkInfo, subLinkNames : $subLinkName, subLinkURLs : $subLinkURL}; 
        });
        // Optionally, you could put the name and url in the array object here but not sure which is better to do   
        //$subLink =[]; 
        //$('.linkSection').each(function(index, element) {
        //$subLink.push($(this).find('#subLinkName').attr('value'));
        //$subLink.push($(this).find('#subLinkURL').attr('value'));
        //});   
    }else{
        //alert('hey');
        $data = {linkName: $linkName, linkURL: $linkURL,  linkID : $linkID, linkDescription : $linkInfo};
    }
    //Uncomment to check the data being sent
    //alert(JSON.stringify($data));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/webapps/WebServices/RMSI/rmsi.cfc?method=UpdateRegularLink",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify($data),
        //dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {                    
            $('#response').css({margin:'20px', padding: '20px', backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}).append('<h2>Server Response:</h2><br />');;
        },
        error: function(data,status,error){
            alert(data+': '+status+': '+error);
        }
    }).done(function(apiResponse) {
        $( "#response" ).append( apiResponse );
    });
});
```

CFC Component:

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="UpdateRegularLink" access="remote" returntype="any">    

    <!--- ***********************************************************************************
    ' 10/03/2013 - Kudos to E. Grosskurth for figuring this out.  When passing arrays of 
    ' Json data we don't need defined parameters.  The getHttpRequestData().content function 
    ' pulls all of the FORM.variables without having to use arguments.  The 
    ' deserializeJSON function turns our comma delimited lists into CF arrays.  -TE
    ' ********************************************************************************** --->
    <cfset params = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />

    <!--- deserialize the request data, so that we can access the individual arguments --->
    <cfset args = #deserializeJSON(params)# />

    <!--- set a base path to wherever our application lies --->
    <cfset bPath = "e:\webapps\NRCNewsApps\rmsi" />
    5
    <!--- Pull back, and parse, our existing xml file --->
    <cffile action="read" file="#bPath#\xml\nav.xml" variable="myxml">  
    <cfset thedoc = XmlParse(myxml)>
    6   
    <!--- Search for the specific node we need to modify.  This is our top level info. --->
    <cfset arynode = XmlSearch(thedoc, "/webpages/course[ @id = '#args.linkID#' ]") />
    <cfset xmlCourse = arynode[1] />    
    7
    <!--- Update the top level information about the link --->
    <cfset arynode[1].linkName.xmlText = "#args.linkName#" />
    <cfset arynode[1].link.xmlText = "#args.linkURL#" />
    <cfset arynode[1].linkInfo.xmlText = "#args.linkDescription#" />
    8
    <!--- Find out if there are sublinks --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(xmlCourse, "subLink")>
        <cfset slNode = XMLSearch(xmlCourse, "subLink") />
        <cfloop from = "1" to="#arrayLen(slNode)#" index="i">
        <!---<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>--->
            <cfset slNode[i].name.xmlText = "#args.subLinkNames[i]#" />
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    9


    <cfdump var="#thedoc#" />
    <cfabort />


  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: The code for that cfc method help.

Comment: The AJAX error is blank, no errors on the code or in the console... Dan I added the cfc

Comment: If the form data is loaded into the url it works with no problems unless the data in the form does not match the data loaded in the url (meaning I changed a form field after it was loaded in the url)

Comment: _The AJAX error is blank_ - do you mean that the AJAX code is falling into the `error:` callback function but the alert does not show the data or is the `error:` callback not being called at all? `alert()` may not be able to handle displaying the data returned, you might try using `console.log()` instead (and view those messages in the browser's javascript console).

Comment: Is your cfc being influenced by an Application.cfc file?  If so, you can add a cfmail tag to the onError() function.  You can also check the exception log of your Cold Fusion server to get clues as to what happened.

Comment: Miguel (the error callback is definetly triggered) the console.log returns blank, the alert returns blank, there is nothing to tell me the issue. Like I said if the data has been loaded into the url and then the submit is triggered it returns data as it should. What i am trying to figure out is why the data isn't passed to the cfc without being loaded into the url

Comment: The code that you posted here does not contain a `console.log()` in the `error:` callback, only an `alert()`.  Change the `alert()` to a `console.log()` to see if you get any information (if you haven't already done that).

Comment: I have done that and it does not log anything

Comment: All three of the arguments are blank when the error is thrown? Have you checked the actual requests being sent back and forth when this happens (using Fiddler, Wireshark, Firebug, or equivalent)?

Comment: It displays the arguments, data and status but not error in the console before the page submits, refreshes or whatever it does when it adds the form data to the url...

Comment: I think the issue is from the fact that you are actually submitting the form and not using jQuery to prevent the default behavior of the button. I would hazard a guess that you do not have an `action` attribute for your <form> - so the browser uses a `GET`, hence why you see the variables in the URL. When you click the button, the form submits anyway, even though you have this JS handler code. Try changing the `submit` button to type `button` and change the JS to use `on("click")` for the button rather than `on("submit")` for the form.

Comment: Sounds Great Scott, I am on furlough and will try that when I get back to work... I was also thinking, Would adding preventdefault do the same thing? I will upcheck your answer if correct, Thanks!

Comment: @ScottStroz this works, if you want to add copy and paste this as the answer I will surely check it. Also please add that you have to put method="post" so the data doesn't still get stored in the URL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#update submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        data = form.serialize(),
        action = form.attr('action');
    $.post(action, data)
        .done(function() {
            alert('Success!');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Sorry, please try again.');
        });
});
```

Obviously your form will need to have an action attribute.